# Translate C to Pascal

Tags: c, freepascal

I'm trying to translate the header of libfprint (fprint.h) to Pascal, but I find a structure that can not understand and some tools such as "C2Pas" only send error.

The structure is as follows:

```
struct fp_dscv_dev **fp_discover_devs(void);
```

Where fp_dscv_dev this only declared as follows:

```
/* structs that applications are not allowed to peek into */
struct fp_dscv_dev;
```

What would be the equivalent in Pascal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have 2 different things here. `fp_discover_devs` is a function declaration and `fp_dscv_dev` is a forward declaration of `struct`.

Comment: Thanks for answer @icepack, What is necessary to use double "*" this function? thanks

Comment: That just means a pointer to a pointer. There is no single obvious reason for that choice here, but it often appears in the interface to complicated heap-like objects that the library or OS may want to reconfigure without having to notify all the users (Mac OS did this for memory management before OS X in order to support chips without full virtual memory support).

Comment: It is normally easier to translate Pascal to C than the other way around, Pascal is a too restrictive language. Have you considered going that route instead?

Comment: I had not considered the idea @vonbrand but since it is a new project, I think is a good idea to start using more C and C++ for this project.

Comment: vonbrand: modern Pascals like Delphi and FreePascal support quite a lot, and go a long way providing similar functionality to most of  the classic C++ features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opague pointers are traditionally basic pointers in Pascal (like void * in c).

If you really want to the struct aspect to return define it as a record without fields:

```
    Type 
       fp_dscv_dev   = record end;
```

As said in the comments, a ** is a double reference
Since in most modern pascals references can't be in parameter and return value declarations, we define additional types for them:

```
       pfp_dscv_dev  = ^fp_dscv_dev
       ppfp_dscv_dev = ^pfp_dscv_dev
```

Finally the declaration itself is

```
   function fp_discover_devs:ppfp_dscv_dev; cdecl;
```